# popup window when hover over a table cell html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a JavaScript application, and I found a nice library [qtip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2). My goal is when the user hover the mouse over each cell in the table, a different information is displayed. That library I mentioned above does the job of displaying the info in a small pop up window. However, I'm not sure how to set up this function in other to display each cell's particular content when hover over it. Does someone have an idea how can I accomplish that?

```
function showInfo()
    {
            $('#demo-mouse').qtip({
                content : 'I position myself at the current mouse position',
                position : {
                    my : 'top left',
                    target : 'mouse',
                    viewport : $(window),       //keep it on-screen at all time if possible
                    adjust : {
                        x : 10, y : 10
                    }
                },
                hide : {
                    fixed : true                // Helps to prevent the tooltip from hiding occassionaly when tracking!
                },
                style : 'ui-tooltip-shadow'
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extented `content` property and use classes in the elements you want to show the tips:

```
$('.selector').qtip({
    content: {
        text: function(api) {
            // Retrieve content from custom attribute of the $('.selector') elements.
            return $(this).attr('data-tip');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. One last thing before I give you the answer. How can I modify my `<td>` in other to have that `.selector` you've mentioned?

Comment: Just add a `class` attibute to each one `<td class="selectorOrAnythingYouWant">` or add a class or id to the table and change the selector in this code to match: `<table id="MyTable">` and `$("#MyTable td")`.

Comment: I did make those changes you've suggested, however they are not working. 
`<td class="selector" style="background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);">1</td>`
`<td class="selector" style="background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);">1</td>`

Comment: When I refresh my brother, it does not work. However, when I call the function from the firebug terminal, then it starts working, wondering why.

Comment: You just have to call it on the `$(document).ready()` event to fire it on load.